# Get an int at the beginning of a string with PHP

Tags: php, regex

**Supposing** I have:

```
$yeah='71263andsomemore632';
```

**How** may I get two variables like this:

```
$intAtBeginning=71263;
$theRest='andsomemore632';
```

I really don't know how to do this, since both integers might have a different length. I promise I will research on whatever you help me with, to understand it and sleep happy today  ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way would be to use [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

```
list($intAtBeginning, $theRest) = sscanf($yeah, '%d%s');
echo $intAtBeginning.'<br>'.$theRest;
```

Comment: Modern line without `list()`: `[$intAtBeginning, $theRest] = sscanf($yeah, '%d%s');` or the syntax for reference variables: `sscanf($yeah, '%d%s', $intAtBeginning, $theRest);`